# jQuery Ajax + Classic ASP return error 'unexpected end of input'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I have two problems on this combination.

1. After Ajax always return error (unexpected end of input),In localhost it still can save date successfully, seems not a big problem.
2. The code works in my localhost but does not work in 1App Server(http://www.1apps.net/), I had tried to submit a technique question and them had a response quickly with this way http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/98/ajax-with-classic-asp-using-jquery

However, I think the way in that article should be working but I am confused why my code is only work in localhost and other web server but not 1App. The following is my code:

ASP:

```
if request.QueryString("action")="CostUpdate" then

Response.ContentType = "application/json"

a = request.form("GI")
b = request.form("GP")
c = request.form("NA")


Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "Select * From Cost where CostDate = #" & date() & "# and CostItem ='" & a & "'"
rs.open sql,conn,1,3

if rs.eof then

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "Select * From Cost"
rs.open sql,conn,1,3

rs.addnew
rs("CostDate")=date()
rs("CostItem")=a
rs("CostAmount")=c
rs("CostNumber")= b * c
rs.update

else

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "Select * From images where CostDate =#" & adid & "# and CostItem = " & a
rs.open sql,conn,1,3

rs("CostAmount")=c
rs("CostNumber")=b * c
rs.update

end if
end if
```

JS

```
var $GoodsId = $("#costtable tbody").find("tr").eq(c).find("input").eq(1).val();
    var $GoodsPrice = $("#costtable tbody").find("tr").eq(c).find("input").eq(2).val();
    var $NewAmount = $("#costtable tbody").find("tr").eq(c).find("input").eq(3).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'work.asp?action=CostUpdate',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            GI: $GoodsId,GP: $GoodsPrice,NA: $NewAmount

        },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.info("CallAjax");
            console.info('An error occured.. ' + xhr.responseText + '..' + error);
        },
        success: function () {
            console.info("Sucess");
        }
    });
```

Comment: If only you *had* followed that article.

Comment: Why do you set your content type to Json in asp page?! it seems there is no data to push back

Comment: @AliSheikhpour do you mean this "Response.ContentType = "application/json" ??  As I know i can receive json content if i put this statement there, am i wrong?

Comment: Json is used to transmit data. your asp page generates no data and is only updating database rows, So you dont need to use Json datatype. However I think your main problem might be that the 1App can not connect to database (or doesn't support asp). What message do you receive at your javascript console?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour the regular creation works, I mean sending date by form and method is "Post", so I ensure 1App support Asp. The Ajax error message is "unexpected end of input", the thing makes me confused is the same error message occurs in my localhost, but data is created, the same code on another pay server works as well, only free 1App...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several problems in asp code:

1. Don't open new sql command when **rs** is still open. So I created a
   new recordset (rs2) to use inside the **if** block.
2. You don't need to recreate rs for every action. so i deleted repeating
   **createobject**.
3. There is no need to set contentType to Json because no data is generated. You are only updating database.
4. Use **rs.open sql,objcon,2,2** when you want to use sql update command.
5. use **rs.close** and also **set rs=nothing** to free server memory.
6. there is no definition for parameter **adid**. do you defined it somewhere else?
7. You are **posting** data to asp page not **getting**. So you have to use
   **request.form** in first line and also send parameter "action" within posted data.
8. is this entire asp codes? where do you define **conn**?

Besides the error "unexpected end of input" is not an ASP error. You may forgot } inside JavaScript codes. the presented code is OK, check entire your code.

```
if request.form("action")="CostUpdate" then

a = request.form("GI")
b = request.form("GP")
c = request.form("NA")


Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sql = "Select * From Cost where CostDate = #" & date() & "# and CostItem ='" & a & "'"
rs.open sql,conn,1,3

if rs.eof then

sql = "Select * From Cost"
rs2.open sql,conn,2,2

rs2.addnew
rs2("CostDate")=date()
rs2("CostItem")=a
rs2("CostAmount")=c
rs2("CostNumber")= b * c
rs2.update
rs2.close

else

sql = "Select * From images where CostDate =#" & adid & "# and CostItem = " & a
rs2.open sql,conn,2,2
rs2("CostAmount")=c
rs2("CostNumber")=b * c
rs2.update
rs2.close

end if
rs.close
end if

set rs=nothing
set rs2=nothing
```

Comment: Thank you!! @Ali Sheikhpour, the ASP code looks better after your revising. Now I decided to put my website on Azure, it works.